Is there a way in mongo db to arrange items such that items with identical field are not displayed together?
I have some data in this format
[
  {
    "userId": 0,
    "docId": 0,
    "createdDate": "2024-03-20 09:22:24.492961"
  },
 {
    "userId": 0,
    "docId": 2,
    "createdDate": "2024-03-20 09:22:24.492961"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "docId": 1,
    "createdDate": "2024-01-15 09:22:24.492975"
  },
{
    "userId": 1,
    "docId": 4,
    "createdDate": "2024-01-15 09:22:24.492975"
  },
{
    "userId": 2,
    "docId": 5,
    "createdDate": "2024-01-15 09:22:24.492975"
  }
]

I want to order this such that two documents from same user are not returned together.
Expected Result
[
  {
    "userId": 0,
    "docId": 0,
    "createdDate": "2024-03-20 09:22:24.492961"
  },
{
    "userId": 2,
    "docId": 5,
    "createdDate": "2024-01-15 09:22:24.492975"
  }
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "docId": 1,
    "createdDate": "2024-01-15 09:22:24.492975"
  },
 {
    "userId": 0,
    "docId": 2,
    "createdDate": "2024-03-20 09:22:24.492961"
  },
{
    "userId": 1,
    "docId": 4,
    "createdDate": "2024-01-15 09:22:24.492975"
  },
]

I tried using aggregation pipeline to group items by user and fetching only the first items and then the second items but when there are hundreds of users and hundreds of documents, I would want to mix it such that it is not sequential. Essentially making it seem random.

If you just want a random ordering, a canonical way would be just $rand to set a random field and $sort on it.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "randomKey": {
        "$rand": {}
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "randomKey": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "randomKey": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

From what you have described, it is achievable through $setWindowFields (Although not quite "random" in my opinion).
In $setWindowFields, partition by $userId and compute 2 fields, grouping and orderWithinGroup.

grouping: the partition that this document belongs to. For this example, we just take userId
orderWithinGroup: relative order within the partition. We use $rank to compute it

With the $sort of {"orderWithinGroup": 1, "grouping": 1}, you should able to achieve desired sorting.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "partitionBy": "$userId",
      "sortBy": {
        "docId": 1
      },
      "output": {
        "grouping": {
          "$first": "$userId"
        },
        "orderWithinGroup": {
          "$rank": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "orderWithinGroup": 1,
      "grouping": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "grouping": "$$REMOVE",
      "orderWithinGroup": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

While this approach works for most cases, in case where a user has exponentially more docs than the other, it does not ensure that docs from same user are not returned together. What I ended up doing is calculating weights based on created date and some other metrics then sorting by that weight.
